# if else conditions executed at the same time in swift

Tags: swift

I'm parsing this json from a REST API with SwiftyJSON:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": 201,
    "description": "success"
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "5951e8eee0207e049c339691",
      ......
    }
  ]
}
```

After sending the request with Alamofire and getting the response is when I run into an issue:

```
case .success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)

                    if json["status"]["code"].intValue ==  201 {
                        self.jsonData = json["result"].arrayValue
                        self.mytableView.reloadData()
                        print("realoded tableView")
                    }else{
                        HUD.show(.error)
                        HUD.hide(afterDelay: 0.5)
                        HUD.flash(.label("message"), delay: 3.0){ _ in
                            print("fail message")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

`myTableView` reloads the data, and the console shows the print message. However, the HUD is also showing a message, and the console logs the fail message.

P.S. I have also tried to compare as a string with `json["result"]["code"].stringValue == "201"`. This does the same tableview update, but the hud is shown the hud is managed with PKHUD library.

Comment: Without context, it is hard to find the problem. Could it be that this code is executed multiple times (with different data)? Have you tried using the debugger to step through the code (with breakpoints)?

Comment: yes in id i did i call the function where all this get executed on viewDidLoad() and scrollViewDidScroll() but the second one does not run until scroll begin.

Comment: i guess i find it the problem is that i call the function again in scrollViewDidScroll() and get executed even when the view does not begin to scroll, Commented all the code in the scrollViewDidScroll() and solved